# How to gets user id and returns his posts with their comments n angular 6

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6

How gets all users from their **user id** and iterate it, and when i click a specific user i get all his post and comments?

you can fetch the posts from this API: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

and their comments from this API: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments

Here is a my test **stackblitz** project:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g5fqzi

```
getUserPosts(userId: number) {
  this.http.get(`${this._postsURL}`)

  //.pipe(filter(data => userId === userId))
  //this.http.get(`${this._postsURL}/${userId}`)
    .subscribe(data => {
     //this.UserPosts  = data;
      let resources = data[userId];
      this.UserPosts = resources;
      console.log(this.UserPosts);
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qusay, if I understood right you are trying to get only the posts of a specific userId.

If you are making a new HTTP request you could pass the userId in the request get only the posts you want like this:

```
this.http.get(`${this._postsURL}?userId=${userId}`)
  .subscribe(data => {
    // do stuff
  });
```

But if you have already all posts in memory (from a previous request) and just want to select the ones of a specific userId you could do this:

```
const userPosts = this._postsArray.filter(post => post.userId == userId);
```

or if there is always only one result, you can use the method `find` instead of `filter`, just keep in mind that find returns the value and filter returns a new array with the value.

`const userPosts = this._postsArray.find(post => post.userId == userId);`

I hope this helps.